# Securing JSON request and response from WCF service

Tags: json, wcf, security

We have developed an application for iPad which consumes data from WCF service.
iPad application sends request in JSON data format to WCF service and receives response in JSON data format from WCF service.
We found during penetration test that users can manipulate request JSON data like changing role of logged in user to get higher privileged user data in the application.
JSON request data is not encrypted. It is plain text data. Same is the case with response.

How to secure request and response JSON data?

We can encrypt request at iPad and decrypt at WCF side and do similarly for response JSON data. This will add overhead. 
Another option is to compute hash for request JSON data at iPad and send it as input to WCF. At WCF side, compute hash again for actual request JSON data and compare. This will help to identify whether request is manipulated or not.

Any suggestions???

Can we use ProtectionLevel Property on Operation Contract???

As per MSDN ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347692%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) article we can encrypt and sign operation contract. In this case, what changes should be made at iPad application side???

Comment: You can't secure *anything* coming from a client. Period. That's the purpose for server-side validation.

Comment: What data are you most concerned about? Profile data, like user level, etc.?

Comment: User roles, levels, privileges should be stored only on the server.

Comment: When users log into the application, iPad generates a request to get user profile, and role data stored in server. In penetration test, request data is modified to get user profile of other users than logged in user. How can we make sure that request is not modified?

Comment: Hi, @Raghu. You can't control anything coming from the client, because someone could write their own app (or modify yours) to send bogus info to your server.

Comment: Typical way to deal with this is keep profile info on the server. It's ok to share it with the client, but don't trust the profile info coming from the client.

Comment: Jonathan it has been raised as an security flaw in the application. Users can modify using app to data that they are not authorized to view it.

Comment: Following is the scenario - User 1 logs into the application.(Authentication is done by third party app) iPad app receives login token (User1) which contains user name. iPad app then makes request to get user role profile. During this process, others can penetrate request to get User2 data. WCF sees that User2 is just another parameter to function. WCF make request to server to get User2 role profile data and sends it back. Actually we should send User1 role profile data.

Comment: I'll continue talking with you in chat.

Comment: Oh, I can't talk with you in chat yet because your reputation points are not high enough. Is there any way that the authentication server can provide you and the client a common authentication token so that you can validate their identity (just for that one session) via SSL? That would be the way to do it.

Comment: I checked Chat option and its not available. Sorry for that. We are using SSL for http encryption. I think I need to go with Hash generation for request and response data. If request is modified then will raise an error to client. Lets hope this solves the problem. I will update you on our implementation.